# How can I prevent SubmitDiagInfo from using high CPU?

Tags: macos, launchd

I have a problem where the process `SubmitDiagInfo` uses high CPU on an regular basis (see screenshot). Killing the process and restarting the computer has no effect.

[image: Graph of CPU usage in a type square-wave type pattern]

I tried unloading the service using this command:
`sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.SubmitDiagInfo.plist`

But it requires SIP to be disabled, something I'd rather not do.

How can I prevent or find the cause of SubmitDiagInfo using high CPU on macOS Monterey 12.6.6?

Comment: What’s the question?  Unload the `SubmitDiagInfo.plist` or diagnose what is causing the high CPU usage?

Comment: Just quit the process...

Comment: If I quit the process, it restarts like 5 seconds later...

Comment: Please add your macOS version to the OP. What do you class as 'high CPU'? That graph is the whole system CPU load over a period, and so will be contributed to by every other process running. You would need to show that `SubmitDiagInfo` specifically has a problem. As to it restarting, the system is designed to do that as Apple consider it to be an essential OS component. I despair when I read people wanting to disable key parts of the OS (most of which runs as background processes) without understanding what they are for, just cos they are considered to be causing an issue.

Comment: Also, the graph doesn't show high CPU load, the CPU is mostly idle even at the load "peaks".

Comment: @AndyGriffiths Yes, I recognise that this is an important process, and likely indicates a deeper problem. But this is causing an issue. I'm not wanting to disable the process, just prevent it from locking up the system.

Comment: @nohillside The graph underrepresents the issue, the system often locks up until `SubmitDiagInfo` stops using so much CPU

Answer (score 0):

SubmitDiagInfo is a process that periodically sends your analytics data to Apple.

Disable everything in *System Settings > Privacy & Security > Analytics & Improvements* to be sure.

Comment: Thank you. Everything is already disabled here however.